# How to create dynamic query to fetch data from custom setting

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I want to create a generic component on which I will pass custom setting name as parameter and also list of fields which I want to get from custom setting.

So can we do this in Salesforce?

Comment: What did you try to do about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement it yourself using String.

Something like this:

```
public List<SObject> getCustomSettingList(String customObjectName,Set<String> FieldList){
    if(FieldList.size()==0)
        return null;
    String soqlQuery = 'SELECT ';
    for(String field:FieldList){
        soqlQuery+=field;
    }
    soqlQuery+' FROM '+customObjectName;
    return Database.query(soqlQuery);
}
```